# Docker: How to print the last n characters of a field using --format

Tags: docker, go-templates

I'm trying to write a docker formatter that will make the output of `docker container ls` more readable. I would like to truncate the Image field so that only the last `n` characters are printed (some of the images i deal with have quite long paths).

E.g: How do I modify `{{.Image}}` so that output goes from this:

```
docker container ls --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}"
43b15196a114        nginx:1.17.2-alpine
5cfb448d2aa5        this/container/has/a/very/long/path/elasticsearch:6.8.0
```

To this:

```
43b15196a114        nginx:1.17.2-alpine
5cfb448d2aa5        th/elasticsearch:6.8.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `slice` function for this, but there are several caveats:

1. Slice indexes should not exceed array (string) bounds.
2. `.Image` field is of some strange type (not string), so you should evaluate it to string (using `print`) and assign some name to it.

```
docker container ls --format 'table {{.ID}}\t{{with $i:=(print .Image)}}{{if le (len $i) 20}}{{$i}}{{else}}{{slice $i (slice $i 20|len)}}{{en
d}}{{end}}'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes